# How to get ID of HTML element?

Tags: javascript

So the code below will get the ID of the BODY elementL

```
var bodyId = document.body.id;
```

How can I get the ID of the HTML element using plain ole' JavaScript?

Comment: Umm...you just did? - which HTML element do you want the Id of?

Comment: @slandau: No, that's the ID of the `body` element. The OP wants the ID of the `html` element.

Comment: ooooh, the html tag. i refer to them as tags not elements. i refer to an html element - anything on the page that's valid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`document.documentElement.id`

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].id
```